# additional parenthesis when allocating a space

Tags: python, pointers, memory-management, ctypes

I have the following line in a code. I know more or less what it does - allocates some memory for an array of buffers. I am trying to investigate the meaning of the syntax - what are the additional parenthesis used for? The content inside the first parenthesis doesn't look like a function. I saw that the construct of double parentheses is used if one function is embedded in another one, but it still doesn't look like that. Moreover when deleting no_ofBuffers variable (as if it was just 1) does not make a 1 - buffer array, the variable itself is necessary, otherwise in next parts of the code the application crashes.

```
buffers = (ct.POINTER(ct.c_int8*buf_size)*no_ofBuffers)()
```

Does somebody have more experience with constructs like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here's the official *ctypes* doc page: [[Python]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) (you might want to take a look at the **Arrays** section).

The rule that always applies when dealing a complex expression is: break it in simpler ones. I'm going to start from the inside (pointing all the intermediary steps), and do it in a *Python* console (also changing some variable names for clarity):

> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> import ctypes
> >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
> 'Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'
> >>>
> >>> # Dummy values for numeric constants
> ...
> >>> INNER_ARR_SIZE = 8  # Replacement for buf_size
> >>> OUTER_ARR_SIZE = 10  # Replacement for no_ofBuffers
> >>>
> >>> # Declare all intermediary types
> ...
> >>> Int8Arr = ctypes.c_int8 * INNER_ARR_SIZE  # Innermost "()"
> >>> Int8ArrPtr = ctypes.POINTER(Int8Arr)  # Pointer
> >>> Int8ArrPtrArr = Int8ArrPtr * OUTER_ARR_SIZE  # Outermost "()"
> >>>
> >>> # Use a human readable name for our final type
> ...
> >>> Buffers = Int8ArrPtrArr
> >>>
> >>> Buffers
> <class '__main__.LP_c_byte_Array_8_Array_10'>
> >>> type(Buffers)
> <class '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'>
> >>>
> >>> # At the end just instantiate the new type (that's what the "()" at the end do) to a default constructed value
> ...
> >>> buffers = Buffers()  # THIS is the equivalent of your (complex) expression
> >>> buffers
> <__main__.LP_c_byte_Array_8_Array_10 object at 0x00000235F614A9C8>
> >>> type(buffers)
> <class '__main__.LP_c_byte_Array_8_Array_10'>
> >>> len(buffers)
> 10
> >>>
> >>> # It's similar to what the line below does
> ...
> >>> i = ctypes.c_int()
> >>> i
> c_long(0)
> ```

Comment: Thank you, very well explained. The most confusing operation I find multiplication of a type and the magical result - an array out of it. But maybe this is a common trick in python.

Comment: Yes, *ctypes* types inherit *Python* sequence types behavior, e.g.: `[8] * 3` will yield `[8, 8, 8]`.

Comment: *BTW*: Could you please mark the answer as a solution, so others are also aware that it solved your problem?

Comment: Ok, thank you once again. I forgot about it, it is my first input into stackoverflow.